# How to push UITableview to under navigation bar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationbar

I am working on a UI which has transparent navigation bar. I used this

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setShadowImage:[UIImage new]];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:YES];
```

Now I want the UITableView should start from top instead of offset like 64.
How to achieve that?

Comment: Hide navigation bar for this particular view

Answer (score 0):

You can set it in storyboard or xib property panel.

[image]

Or you can do as below:

```
[self setAutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets:YES];
[self setEdgesForExtendedLayout:UIRectEdgeAll];
```

This should be done before `viewWillAppear` is invoked.